# Strings with start and end time to datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

For a project I need to parse a few date strings. One date is given, which is the Monday of the week, for example: Feb 16, 2015.

Then, I have managed to extract a list of dates which looks like this:

```
['Wednesday', '11:00AM', '7:00PM']  
['Friday', '10:15AM', '4:30PM']  
['Sunday', '12:00AM', '5:00PM']
```

Where the first value is obviously the day, the second value is the starting time and the last value is the ending time (it's for events).

I would like to convert this to actual python `datetime` objects, but it must align with the starting date.

What I have tried so far is using this:

```
# Beginning of week
BoW = datetime.strptime('Feb 16, 2015', "%b %d, %Y")

# List of days
for day in days:
    # Find the Day of the Week
    # This outputs a number, 0 = Monday, 6 = Sunday
    DoW = table.index(tr)

    schedule.append({
        'start' : BoW + timedelta(days=DoW),
        'end' : BoW + timedelta(days=DoW)
    })
```

As you can see, this will only successfully set the date, but not the hour/minute. Is there a way to easily achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse out the time with `strptime()` as well:

```
timevalue = datetime.strptime(timecomponent, '%I:%M%p').time()
```

`%I` is a 12-hour clock hour value (so between 1 and 12) and `%p` is the AM or PM qualifier.

You can then use [`datetime.datetime.combine()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to combine that time component with your date:

```
BoW = datetime.strptime('Feb 16, 2015', "%b %d, %Y").date()
start = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%I:%M%p').time()
end = datetime.strptime(end_time, '%I:%M%p').time()
start, end = datetime.combine(BoW, start), datetime.combine(BoW, end)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> BoW = datetime.strptime('Feb 16, 2015', "%b %d, %Y").date()
>>> datetime.strptime('11:00AM', '%I:%M%p').time()
datetime.time(11, 0)
>>> datetime.combine(BoW, _)
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 11, 0)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your detailed explanation! It worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what type of situation you are in, but you might try the cool NLP time parsing library `parsedatetime`. It would let you do something like this:

```
import parsedatetime

cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
WoY_timetuple, status = cal.parse("Feb 16, 2015")
DoW_timetuple, status = cal.parse("Wednesday", sourceTime=WoY_timetuple)
start, status = cal.parseDT("11:00AM", sourceTime=DoW_timetuple)
end, status = cal.parseDT("7:00PM", sourceTime=DoW_timetuple)
```

So you can easily set the parsing context to get each time of day string into a full `datetime` object. You would need to make sure you carefully handle the status codes returned by the `.parse` method. If your input data has some variability in date formatting this approach could save time, otherwise Martijn's approach is probably a lot safer.

Comment: This looks very promising too! Thanks for this suggestion.